# VB.NET SOLDIWORKS automation changing global variables values in equations

Tags: vb.net, global-variables, equation, solidworks

Hello I am trying to automate SOLIDWORKS models editing using equations table and particularly global variables values that I am trying to edit programmatically from my standalone app. The problem is that often SOLDIWORKS shows the syntax error on all global variables and sometimes it doesn't. The code I use to change the value:

```
Dim LowerFilmWidth as single = 420
Set_EquationValue(swTFVPM_FSL.GetEquationMgr(), "LowerFilmWidth", LowerFilmWidth)
```

And the function looks like this:

```
    Function Set_EquationValue(ByVal eqMgr As SldWorks.EquationMgr, ByVal GlobalVariableName As String, ByVal EquationValue As Single) As Boolean

        'Declare Variables
        Dim index As Integer = -1
        Dim strEquation As String = $"""{GlobalVariableName}""={EquationValue}"
        Dim count As Integer = eqMgr.GetCount()
        Dim iGlobalVariable As Integer

        'Loop through equations
        For iGlobalVariable = 0 To count - 1
            Dim eqName As String = Trim(Split(eqMgr.Equation(iGlobalVariable), "=")(0))
            eqName = eqName.Substring(1, eqName.Length - 2) 'Removing the "" symbols from the GlobalVariableName

            If String.Compare(eqName, GlobalVariableName, True) = 0 Then
                index = iGlobalVariable
                Exit For
            End If
        Next iGlobalVariable

        'Set equation value if found
        If index <> -1 Then
            eqMgr.Equation(index) = strEquation
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
```

What is the problem and how do I fix it? It literally sometimes does and sometimes does not work on the same global variables. Same goes for syntax error. It sometimes appears and sometimes doesn't

Comment: What is the syntax error you get in SolidWorks? Does it disappear after a force rebuild?

Comment: That's the thing that there's no description it just says "Syntax error" on the variable and red crosses next to each global variable and each equation.... basically every row in equations row. Rebuilding doesn't do anything, only thing that SOMETIMES helps is restarting SOLIDWORKS

Comment: Have you checked that your code is definitely only setting a single Global Variable as intended? If you cut down your code to directly set a known global variable, something like `eqMgr.Equation(index) = $"""{GlobalVariableName}""={EquationValue}"` with `index` set to the known index of a global variable in a model document can you still reproduce the syntax error?

Comment: Yes! Itš kind of a random itš like 50/50 if it will appear. What I have noticed taht this happens on every second time I run some model editing like this. ANd what I have foudn so far is that SOLDIWORKS doesn't actually ``.exitapp``` but if I close it in task manager, teh issue seems to go away

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce that error myself using SolidWorks 2023, I'm not sure what is causing it in your case. A quick google suggested [reinstalling VBA](https://support.plmgroup.eu/hc/en-us/articles/360017605397-SOLIDWORKS-TUTORIAL-How-to-fix-the-error-The-Syntax-of-this-equation-is-incorrect-) can help, though I'm not convinced that's the cause it may be worth a look. If it is failing with the simplified code sometimes then it may well be a SolidWorks based issue, rather than anything specific with your code.

Comment: I had the same issue recently. Adding spaces seems to have resolve it somehow. It seems silly but try: """{GlobalVariableName}"" = {EquationValue}"

Comment: This did not help as on the second running it returned errors again. I suspect it's about quitting SOLIDWORKS where it does not actually completely quit it